# How to remove schema validation in mongoose (mongodb)?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have `MongoDB server version: 5.0.6` installed and used `"mongoose": "^6.0.14"` to create a model validation. Example of model:

```
const User = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  relationId: {
    type: Number,
    unique: true,
    required: 'Id in SQL DB'
  },
});
```

Now I don't need the `relationId` to be required. Actually I want to delete it from the DB but I can't. And I can't to change the behavior of the validator. I tried:

Modified the Mongoose schema to:

```
const User = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String
  }
});
```

As admin in the DB threw the command:

```
db.runCommand({ collMod: "users", validator: {}, validationLevel: "off" })
```

Returns an `{ok:1}` but when I try to insert a document via Mongoose still has the error: `11000 duplicate key error collection: collection.users index: relationId already exists`

I used as well

`db.users.updateMany({}, {$unset: {relationId: ''}})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you had the `unique: true` part in the schema definition mongoose has already created a unique index in the database. Removing it from the schema definition doesn't automatically remove the index from the database. You should drop the index manually. You can use [syncIndexes](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/connection.html#connection_Connection-syncIndexes) to remove the index from the database.